# Sound in splash screen or launch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen, avaudioplayer

I want to add sound while showing the splash screen,when it turns to the home screen the other sound is playing?My question is where should i have to specify the sound code for producing the sound while splash screen came?

Comment: how are you showing your splash using Default.png or have made separate view for that???

Comment: @spider1983 im using Default.png

Answer (score 0):

Put in your `application didFinishLaunching` but be sure to instantiate it in you .h and .m.

Something like this should do your problem:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURMUSICNAME.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1;
        player.currentTime = 0;
        player.volume = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to stop it:

```
[player stop];
```

or pause it :

```
[player pause];
```

and also import it in your header file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and add this to your header ......

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

Comment: i tried yur way but. The sound came only after showing the splash screen

Answer (score 0):

i Guess you can try this :

First of all Add **AVFoundation.Framework** in your project

```
in AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary  
  *)launchOptions
  {
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] 
  autorelease];
  self.navigate = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigate;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

 // Add this line to present splash;
  [self.viewController displayScreen];

  return YES;
 }
```

Then in your rootViewController ie your first viewController

```
in .h
```

Add this Frame work

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

 AVAudioPlayer *avSound; //define this

-(void)displayScreen;
-(void)removeScreen;
```

and then add these two methods in your .m

```
-(void)displayScreen
{
   UIView *splashView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]autorelease];
   splashView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage 
   imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
   UIViewController *displayViewController=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
displayViewController.view = splashView;
[self presentModalViewController:displayViewController animated:NO];

      NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  
     URLForResource:@"soundFile"withExtension:@"mp3/caf or whatever"];
      avSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
     [avSound play];//play sound;

    [self performSelector:@selector(removeScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];


 }

 -(void)removeScreen
  {
   [[self modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

     if ([avSound isPlaying])
       [avSound stop];//stop playing sound;
  }
```

then release it in

```
-(void)dealloc
 {
       [super dealloc];
      [avSound release];
  }
```

Its working for me,hope helps you too.

Comment: it will works for iPhone4s we have change the coordinates for iPad and iPhone5.